# command not found: newrelic-lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, newrelic

Trying to use the newrelic cli to integrate my aws account to new relic, but have run into this hiccup. I'm following these steps:https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/serverless-function-monitoring/aws-lambda-monitoring/enable-lambda-monitoring/account-linking

After installing `pip3 install newrelic-lambda-cli`, I then try to run the command

`newrelic-lambda integrations install --nr-account-id YOUR_NR_ACCOUNT_ID \ --nr-api-key YOUR_NEW_RELIC_USER_KEY`

and get the following error:

`zsh: command not found: newrelic-lambda`

I then check python to see if I have installed the package, and I am seeing that it is installed:

[image]

Anyone know why I'm unable to find the newrelic-lambda command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just uninstalled and reinstalled and it is working now. I believe it was because my boto3 was of a lower level

```
pip uninstall newrelic-lambda

pip install newrelic-lambda
```